# Assign value to property via expression-tree

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I want to implement an expression-tree for assignment-calls to properties of my model. So I am able to call it like this:

```
UpdateFeature(myFeature, x => x.MyProperty, "newValue");
```

which would set the `myFeature.MyProperty` to `"newValue"`.

`myFeature` is of type `MyType`:

```
class MyType 
{ 
    public string MyProperty { get; set; } 
}
```

My `UpdateFeature`-function is this:

```
void UpdateFeature<T, TResult>(T feature, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> e, TResult newValue)
{
    Expression exp = Expression.Assign((MemberExpression)e.Body, Expression.Constant(newValue));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(exp, Expression.Parameter(typeof(T)));
    lambda.Compile().DynamicInvoke(feature);
}
```

However I get an `InvalidOperationException` when calling `Compile`:

> variable 'x' of type 'MyType' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

I also tried using strongly-typed lambda:

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(exp, Expression.Parameter(typeof(T)));
```

with the exact same error appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following simplified version.

```cs
void UpdateFeature<T, TResult>(T feature, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> e, TResult newValue)
{
    var x = e.Parameters[0];
    var exp = Expression.Assign(e.Body, Expression.Constant(newValue));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(exp, x);
    lambda.Compile()(feature);
}
```

Anyway calling this method is ineffective. Compiling lambda takes a lot of time. Without caching compiled methods, better to use just reflection.

Comment: This works, however I have no idea how this is different from the code in my question, despite the `ParameterExpression`. I can't get why that makes a difference, though.

Comment: Less allocations and we simply reused Expression body.

Answer (score 1):

The provided expression is just an expression for the properties getter, not for its setter. So we need to create a `PropertyExpression` first:

```
void UpdateFeature<T, TResult>(T feature, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> e, TResult newValue)
{
    var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    Expression exp = x;
    exp = Expression.Property(exp, ((PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)e.Body).Member));
    exp = Expression.Assign(exp, Expression.Constant(newValue));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(exp, x);
    lambda.Compile().Invoke(feature);
}
```

Comment: If you care about performance, cache compiled function or just use reflection.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv caching the delegates is of course a good idea. Reflection on the other hand won't help at all. The above code highly consists of reflection-basec code. Plus id won't supply strong types, which is why I chosed to use expression-trees in the first place.

Comment: Why then `DynamicInvoke(feature)`? Why not just `lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(exp, x); lambda.Compile()(feature);`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv you're right, I changed the code.